# How to get the maximum value of HID report according to mouse sensor parameters?

Tags: mouse, sensors, hid

I'm making a mouse to joystick converter.The solution is map the maximum and minimum value that the mouse can report to the joystick.How can I get the theoretically maximum or minimum value(not logically,regardless of error) of the mouse HID report according to the parameters of the mouse sensor?

My mouse is logitech G403

I dump the HID descriptor:

```
Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
Usage (Mouse) 09 02  
Collection (Application) A1 01  
    Usage (Pointer) 09 01  
    Collection (Physical) A1 00  
        Usage Page (Button) 05 09  
        Usage Minimum (Button 1) 19 01  
        Usage Maximum (Button 16) 29 10  
        Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
        Logical Maximum (1) 25 01  
        Report Count (16) 95 10  
        Report Size (1) 75 01  
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
        Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
        Logical Minimum (-32767) 16 01 80  
        Logical Maximum (32767) 26 FF 7F  
        Report Size (16) 75 10  
        Report Count (2) 95 02  
        Usage (X) 09 30  
        Usage (Y) 09 31  
        Input (Data,Var,Rel,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 06  
        Logical Minimum (-127) 15 81  
        Logical Maximum (127) 25 7F  
        Report Size (8) 75 08  
        Report Count (1) 95 01  
        Usage (Wheel) 09 38  
        Input (Data,Var,Rel,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 06  
        Usage Page (Consumer Devices) 05 0C  
        Usage (AC Pan) 0A 38 02  
        Report Count (1) 95 01  
        Input (Data,Var,Rel,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 06  
    End Collection C0  
End Collection
```

I can only know the logical maximum and minimum of X and Y from this descriptor,No physical values or units are given here.

Through some rough tests I got the following data:

12000dpi,1000 report rate: the maximum value I measured was about 900

6000dpi,1000 report rate: the maximum value I measured was about 450

12000dpi,125 report rate:  the maximum value I measured was about 8000

Although you can see here that the report values and DPI/report rate vary linearly but I still don't know what the report value really means.

This mouse fps(sampling rate?) is 12000,That's up to 12000 counts per second？
But obviously the report value is not number of counts.